# Merging two arrays in multidimensional array with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I merge two arrays ?

I tried this :

```
var data = {};
var array1 = [1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1];
var array2 = [2];
var data = array1.concat(array2);
```

it displays `[1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1 , 2]`

but I want to display the result this way : `[1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1][2]`

Comment: What about `var data = [array1, array2];` ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array1 = [1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1];
var array2 = [2];
var data = [array1,array2];

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```js
var array1 = [1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1];
var array2 = [2];
var data = [array1,array2];
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `push` or `concat` and merge multiple arrays, Below are 2 methods provided to perform the merging of arrays:

```js
//Method 1
var array1 = [1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1];
var array2 = [2];
array1.push.apply(array1, array2)
console.log(array1);

//Method 2
var array1 = [1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1];
var array2 = [2];
var multipleArrays = [array1, array2];
var flatArray = [].concat.apply([], multipleArrays);
console.log(flatArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to push the two arrays into a new, empty array like below.

```
var data = [];
var array1 = [1.79 , 2.33 , 3.1];
var array2 = [2];
data.push(array1, array2);
```